# How to populate a ChoiceBox with objects from a List

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I wan't to populate a `ChoiceBox` from a `List<Object>`. My Object has a name field which i wan't to use that as the choice text.
Of course i need to know which object the user has selected in order to pass the correct data.

FXML Controller:

```
public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {
    UniversitiesService uniService = new UniversitiesServiceImpl();
    List<University> uniList = uniService.getUniversitiesList();
    //uniChoiceBox.setItems(); Need some guidance here
}
```

University Entity:

```
private String universityName;
private String universityURL;
private String[] universityDataNames;

//getters setters
```

Comment: what framework are you using, Post some code and provide more information as to what you intend to do.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the [documentation, specifically about the `converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html#converterProperty)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do

```
uniChoiceBox.getItems().setAll(uniList);
```

If you need to configure the display (i.e. if the `toString()` method in `University` doesn't give the text you need), add a converter:

```
uniChoiceBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<University>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(University uni) {
        return uni.getUniversityName();
    }
    @Override
    // not used...
    public University fromString(String s) {
        return null ;
    }
});
```

Comment: I've totally forgot of the toString() method. Thanks James (for once more)!